# What datatype will have the least amount of overhead when transmitted over WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF webservice that needs to return data in table form, basically just columns and rows of simple text.
Right now, I am using a datatable but that is giving me headaches. Would another type such as a 2D array of strings work effectively well, maybe even better?
What datatype would be best with the least amount of complications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bandwidth seems to be the issue (previous questions etc)...

If the data is simple text strings, then things like GZIP compression may work wonders. I would be very tempted to investigate transforming the `DataTable` into something as simple as tsv (or another delimited form), and run it through a `GZipStream` (encoding line by line). Then send the resultant binary down the wire either as a `Stream` or a `byte[]`. And enable MTOM.

Answer (score 1):

When SvcUtil.exe generates a proxy for clients, it generally converts most 2D array of strings into simple string arrays (string[]).

This would simplify the client proxy generation for you.

I would use the list that provided the optimal services for you.
For example, if you will be iterating one after the other, a normal array may be fine.
If you will need to sort it, perhaps a generic list may be more appropriate.